# Scraping a specific table from a webpage using R

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping

I need to extract a table from the following URL:
http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/records/team/match_results.html?class=2;id=2013;type=year

I only need the table with the caption "Match results"

I used the following code:
library(XML)
ODItable <- readHTMLTable('http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/records/team/match_results.html?class=2;id=2013;type=year')

How do I extract the specific table from here?

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it!

```
library(XML) 
url <- 'http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/records/team/match_results.html?class=2;id=2013;type=year'
ODItable <- readHTMLTable(url)
head(ODItable$`Match results`)

     Team 1    Team 2    Winner    Margin    Ground   Match Date  Scorecard
1     India  Pakistan  Pakistan   85 runs   Kolkata  Jan 3, 2013 ODI # 3315
2     India  Pakistan     India   10 runs     Delhi  Jan 6, 2013 ODI # 3316
3 Australia Sri Lanka Australia  107 runs Melbourne Jan 11, 2013 ODI # 3317
4     India   England   England    9 runs    Rajkot Jan 11, 2013 ODI # 3318
5 Australia Sri Lanka Sri Lanka 8 wickets  Adelaide Jan 13, 2013 ODI # 3319
6     India   England     India  127 runs     Kochi Jan 15, 2013 ODI # 3320
```